# Can't update extended user django model

Tags: django

When I save my model, there is no effect in the database.
What is the problem?

```
class Profil(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

In manage.py shell

```
>>> p = models.Profil.objects.get(user__username='testname')

>>> p.user.is_superuser
False
>>> p.user.is_superuser = True
>>> p.save()
>>> p.user.is_superuser
True
>>> exit()
>>> p = models.Profil.objects.get(user__username='testname')
>>> p.user.is_superuser

False ---------> ????????????????????????????????
```

Comment: p.user.save() will do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
p = models.Profil.objects.get(user__username='testname')
p.user.is_superuser = True
p.user.save()
```